# Textbox Focus lost cursor position in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

after my DB Query and Databind to the Datagrid in Codebehind, the Textbox lost his Focus.
`txtName.Focus()` return the Focus, but the Cursor is at the beginning of the entered text.
How can I set the Cursor to the end of the text?

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. The best way to control cursor position is to use JavaScript. Try search for posts about how to set cursor position. There are many answered questions here with complete code sample.

Comment: My Problem is that the Javascript will be execute before the Codebehind does it. In my Codebehind lost the Textbox the Focus. How can I use Javascript code after the DB search.

Comment: textbox.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(textbox.Page.GetType(),
                                                                "Select-" + edEmpfaengerVersandcode.ClientID,
                                                                String.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').value = '" + textbox.Text + "';", textbox.ClientID),
                                                                true);

Answer (score 1):

In ASP is no Function Select(), or which Libary does I need for.

Answer (score 0):

use .Select() along with .Focus()

TextBox Control

```
<TextBox Name="focusAndPositionMe">This is the text in my text box.</TextBox>
```

Codebehind

```
focusAndPositionMe.Focus()
focusAndPositionMe.Select(focusAndPositionMe.Text.Length, 0)
```